# how to store and retriew xls file into sql database in the form form of byte[] using C# in web application

Tags: asp.net

how to store into sql data base and and how to retriew xls file as xls file from database in the form form of byte[]  using c# in asp.net application. PLEASE Help me

Answer (score 0):

Storing:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("somefile.xls");

    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mytable (document) VALUES (@document)";
    command.Parameters.Add("@document", SqlDbType.Binary, 20).Value = data;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Retrieveing:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT document FROM mytable WHERE document_id = 1";
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            byte[] buffer = GetBytes(reader);
            // TODO: Do something with the excel document
        }
    }
}
```

where `GetBytes` could be defined like this:

```
public byte[] GetBytes(IDataReader reader)
{
    const int CHUNK_SIZE = 2 * 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
    long bytesRead;
    long fieldOffset = 0;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        while ((bytesRead = reader.GetBytes(0, fieldOffset, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            byte[] actualRead = new byte[bytesRead];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, actualRead, 0, (int)bytesRead);
            stream.Write(actualRead, 0, actualRead.Length);
            fieldOffset += bytesRead;
        }
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```